# ASP Net Core - hidden input field data is not passed in the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to pass which button is clicked for the form submit. But the hidden input is not received in the controller. Below are my code snippets

View Model:

```
public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ActionId { get; set; }
}
```

razor(cshtml):

```
<form....>
    <input id="docActionId" name="docActionId" asp-for="ActionId" type="hidden" value="initialValue" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#save_btn").on("click", function ()
{
    $("#docActionId").val("test1");
});

$("#submit_btn").on("click", function ()
{
    $("#docActionId").val("test2");
});
```

I tried showing the current value in alert function if it is change and it did.

In my Controller/Action when I debug, I get a null value for the ActionId variable. I think this is very simple but I don't know what I did wrong.

Please help. I'm stucked in this for 2 hours now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post the controller code that is accepting the action

Comment: Does your controller receive "DocumentViewModel" paramter? Does your action like "public IActionResult Test(DocumentViewModel model)"?

Comment: Please show the controller action the sends the value to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `name="docActionId"` html attributes, they will be generated automatically by Razor.

Specifically by the `asp-for="ActionId"` attribute.

Furthermore the reason this doesn't work is because the `name` attribute which is `docActionId != ActionId` which is the name of the property of your object. So it doesn't know where to bind it to.

```
<form id="myform">
     <input id="docActionId" asp-for="ActionId" type="hidden" value="initialValue" />
     <button type="submit" id="save">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Try this javascript perhaps the form is submitted before you attach the value

```
var saveButton = documnet.getElementById('save')
saveButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   documnet.getElementById('docActionId').value = "test value"
   documnet.getElementById('myform').submit()
})
```

Comment: I tried both of what you said. I change the name and id to "ActionId", I removed the name attribute, neither worked. Still getting null value.

Answer (score 1):

remove the "Id" attribute... that's all you need. "asp-for" does that. adding yours duplicates it kind

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="hidden" id="tag" >
```

type="hidden" didn't work for me with .net core 7 but only hidden keyword worked.

```
<input hidden id="tag">
```